# R/RStudio self creates an unwanted column when using data.table

Tags: r, data.table

The following issue shows up when the code is run in RStudio, no problem when I run from RGui.exe.

Given data.table int:

```
|id|             descricao_complementar|
|1 |                      ACIDO CITRICO|
|2 |ACIDO CITRICO ANIDRO P.A. - 500 GR.|
|3 |        ACIDO CITRICO ANIDRO, 500 G|
|4 | ACIDO CITRICO, NOME ACIDO CITRICO.|
|5 |                     ACIDO CITRICO.|
|6 |ACIDO TRANEXAMICO 250MG COMP CX/12.|
```

and data.table x:

```
|id|                             droga|
|1 |                     ACIDO CITRICO|
|2 |ACIDO CITRICO ANIDRO P.A. - 500 GR|
|3 |        ACIDO CITRICO ANIDRO 500 G|
|4 |  ACIDO CITRICO NOME ACIDO CITRICO|
|5 |                     ACIDO CITRICO|
|6 |ACIDO TRANEXAMICO 250MG COMP CX/12|
```

Then the output for the merge `int <- x[int,on = "id"]` is, as expected:

```
|id|                              droga|              descricao_complementar|
| 1|                      ACIDO CITRICO|                       ACIDO CITRICO|
| 2| ACIDO CITRICO ANIDRO P.A. - 500 GR| ACIDO CITRICO ANIDRO P.A. - 500 GR.|
| 3|         ACIDO CITRICO ANIDRO 500 G|         ACIDO CITRICO ANIDRO, 500 G|
| 4|   ACIDO CITRICO NOME ACIDO CITRICO|  ACIDO CITRICO, NOME ACIDO CITRICO.|
| 5|                      ACIDO CITRICO|                      ACIDO CITRICO.|
| 6| ACIDO TRANEXAMICO 250MG COMP CX/12| ACIDO TRANEXAMICO 250MG COMP CX/12.|
```

However, when I create a new variable
`fim <- int[,.(id, descricao_complementar, droga)]`, a new column is created out of nowhere:

```
|id|             descricao_complementar|                              droga|                        droga_droga|
|1 |                      ACIDO CITRICO|                      ACIDO CITRICO|                      ACIDO CITRICO|
|2 |ACIDO CITRICO ANIDRO P.A. - 500 GR.| ACIDO CITRICO ANIDRO P.A. - 500 GR| ACIDO CITRICO ANIDRO P.A. - 500 GR|
|3 |        ACIDO CITRICO ANIDRO, 500 G|         ACIDO CITRICO ANIDRO 500 G|         ACIDO CITRICO ANIDRO 500 G|
|4 | ACIDO CITRICO, NOME ACIDO CITRICO.|   ACIDO CITRICO NOME ACIDO CITRICO|   ACIDO CITRICO NOME ACIDO CITRICO|
|5 |                     ACIDO CITRICO.|                      ACIDO CITRICO|                      ACIDO CITRICO|
|6 |ACIDO TRANEXAMICO 250MG COMP CX/12.| ACIDO TRANEXAMICO 250MG COMP CX/12| ACIDO TRANEXAMICO 250MG COMP CX/12|
```

On the other hand, if I execute the same command only changing its name from `fim` to `dt` as
`dt <- int[,.(id, descricao_complementar, droga)]`, I get the correct result and the ghost column does not show anymore:

```
|id|             descricao_complementar|                              droga|
|1 |                      ACIDO CITRICO|                      ACIDO CITRICO|
|2 |ACIDO CITRICO ANIDRO P.A. - 500 GR.| ACIDO CITRICO ANIDRO P.A. - 500 GR|
|3 |        ACIDO CITRICO ANIDRO, 500 G|         ACIDO CITRICO ANIDRO 500 G|
|4 | ACIDO CITRICO, NOME ACIDO CITRICO.|   ACIDO CITRICO NOME ACIDO CITRICO|
|5 |                     ACIDO CITRICO.|                      ACIDO CITRICO|
|6 |ACIDO TRANEXAMICO 250MG COMP CX/12.| ACIDO TRANEXAMICO 250MG COMP CX/12|
```

Way further in the code, I do create a droga_droga column, but in previous sessions. My guess is that somehow R/RStudio is messing up the current session with previous sessions command log. So, I have reinstalled either R and RStudio, as well as deleted `%localappdata%\RStudio-Desktop` and .RProj.user alike files/directories, but no success.

Would someone help me to figure out what is going on?

```
> dput(x)
structure(list(id = 1:6, droga = c("ACIDO CITRICO", "ACIDO CITRICO ANIDRO P.A. - 500 GR", 
"ACIDO CITRICO ANIDRO 500 G", "ACIDO CITRICO NOME ACIDO CITRICO", 
"ACIDO CITRICO", "ACIDO TRANEXAMICO 250MG COMP CX/12")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000001a7d1131ef0>, sorted = "id")

> dput(int)
structure(list(descricao_complementar = c("ACIDO CITRICO", "ACIDO CITRICO ANIDRO P.A. - 500 GR.", 
"ACIDO CITRICO ANIDRO, 500 G", "ACIDO CITRICO, NOME ACIDO CITRICO.", 
"ACIDO CITRICO.", "ACIDO TRANEXAMICO 250MG COMP CX/12."), id = 1:6), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000001a7d1131ef0>)

R version 4.0.5 (2021-03-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252  LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252    LC_MONETARY=Portuguese_Brazil.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                       LC_TIME=Portuguese_Brazil.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] xlsx_0.6.5        stringi_1.5.3     stringr_1.4.0     DBI_1.1.1         magrittr_2.0.1    data.table_1.14.0 RSQLite_2.2.7    
[8] RPostgres_1.3.2  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.6      xlsxjars_0.6.1  lifecycle_1.0.0 rlang_0.4.10    cachem_1.0.4    blob_1.2.1      vctrs_0.3.7     ellipsis_0.3.1 
 [9] tools_4.0.5     bit64_4.0.5     bit_4.0.4       hms_1.0.0       fastmap_1.1.0   compiler_4.0.5  pkgconfig_2.0.3 rJava_0.9-13   
[17] memoise_2.0.0
```

Comment: Ronak, dputs added, thank you.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with the data you have shared. I don't get the column `droga_droga`

Comment: That's why I believe this behavior might be related to some  unexpected internal state of either R or RStudio. I can't either replicate it if I run from a fresh start using dput data. Is thre a way to gather the internal state of a session? REgards.

Comment: It's very likely based on what is used to read in the data in the first place. Can you edit that in? Doesn't have to be reproducible.

Comment: I'll infer from the session info that FabioCorrea is using `xlsx::read.xlsx` (though it could be from a database). If xlsx, try using one of the other xlsx-reading packages, including `readxl` and `openxlsx`: they both have the advantage of not requiring java, and both are also generally well-maintained (though `readxl` has not been updated in over a year ... odd). Another possibility: do any of the remaining fields have unicode (not simple ascii, e.g. accents/diacritics) characters? I don't know, but ... since your `LC*` indicates Portuguese, perhaps there is a bug in `data.table`'s joins.

Comment: Thank you both Danielle and r2evans. I use xlsx only for writing some outputs, not for reading input data.  The input is done through SQLite and DBI, and I verify that  the encoding of input data is UTF-8 before moving forward with the code.

Comment: Important observation: The code works when run in RGui.exe. So I believe that it may be related to RStudio. I have already filed an issue with them.

Comment: I doubt it's an issue with encoding, but I still suspect SQLite and DBI because of the insertion of the underscore in the column. Because data.table works by modifying by reference, my guess is that `make.db.names()` is firing off somehow, either earlier in the process and data.table finds it, or it's still somehow acting upon it and, when it sees an illegal name, it changes it, and data.table doesn't remove it because it doesn't conform to what it expects. It's almost certainly not a bug with RStudio. Can you run it with data.table in verbose mode?

Comment: `i.id has same type (integer) as x.id. No coercion needed.
on= matches existing key, using key
Starting bmerge ...
forder.c received 40 rows and 2 columns
bmerge done in 0.000s elapsed (0.000s cpu) 
Constructing irows for '!byjoin || nqbyjoin' ... 0.000s elapsed (0.000s cpu) `

Comment: The following link redirects for the RStudio issue I filed, and has the full code, sample data and comments where the ghost column appears: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/9273#issuecomment-827652452